# problem with owner repositories in npm and package.json _ npm ERR! 400 Bad Request (npm publish)

Tags: node.js, github, npm, package.json

I have a GitHub account contains my **nickname** as a username called **fraybabak**.
and in npm I have a username called my **babakabadkheir**. so I am trying to publish my first package to npm .

in my package.json file I have this:

```
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/fraybabak/smart_random/issues"
  },
  "repository":{
    "url":"https://github.com/fraybabak/smart_random.git"
  },
  "publishConfig": { "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/" },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/fraybabak/smart_random#readme"
```

I know my usernames and scopes are different.
I tried to log in with :

```
npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

and authenticate with GitHub with access_token in password field.

> logged in successfully

so now when I am trying to publish with:

```
npm publish
```

I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/@babakabadkheir%2fsmart_random - scope 'babakabadkheir' in package name '@babakabadkheir/smart_random' does not match repo owner 'fraybabak' in repository element in package.json

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/babyjesus/.npm/_logs/2020-11-15T17_41_09_392Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3):

try update your `package.json` like this:

```
  "repository":{
    "url":"https://github.com/fraybabak/smart_random"
  },
  "publishConfig": { "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/@fraybabak" },
```